# How to disable a button based on inventory

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm currently making a simple text based survival game where you have several different buttons, a couple of which is eat, cook meat, cook fish.  On the right side of the screen is your inventory where you can see how much of something you have.  I want certain buttons like those listed above to be disabled and enabled according to the inventory.  For instance, if you don't have any cooked meat or fish, you shouldn't be able to press the eat button.  If you have no uncooked meat or fish, you shouldn't be able to click on the cook buttons.  Here's the code for one of the buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

displayvars();

$("#cookmeat").click(function () {
    $("#cookfood").hide();
    meat = meat + 2;
    uncookedmeat = uncookedmeat - 2;
    displayvars();

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Run this function after every inventory changing

```
function buttonsState() {
    if(uncookedmeat > 1) {
        $("#cookmeat").show();
    } else {
        $("#cookmeat").hide();
    }
    // $("#cookmeat").toggle(uncookedmeat > 1); <- the same as above

    if(meat > 1) {
        $("#eatmeat").show();
    } else {
        $("#eatmeat").hide();
    }
    // $("#eatmeat").toggle(meat > 1);

    // ....
}
```

It's just showing the main idea, but require a lot of optimization here

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, but I can't test it out just yet because I broke something and it needs fixed.  The moment I'm able to test it out though, I'll let you know if it works.